# How to get products that are found in 2 or more categories

Tags: magento, collections, filter, categories

I have been trying for days now to get a clean solution on how to filter a product collection by 2 or more categories. The products should be in both categoryA and categoryB, not in any of them. 
I have tried multiple solution that I have found on the internet but with no success. The only workaround I have found so far (but I’m not found of it) is using a raw query and then get the collection from the ids:

```
SELECT e.entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity AS e INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS ccp on ccp.product_id=e.entity_id where ccp.category_id =100 or ccp.category_id = 101 group by entity_id having count(*) > 1
```

This would return the list of products that are found in both category 100 and 101. 
However, I hope there is actually a “Magento way” or doing this without needing to execute raw queries. Anyone have clue on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to find a proper solution after a long night of work:

```
$cat_ids = array(4,5,6);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $cat_ids)))
    ->getSelect()
    ->group('entity_id')
    ->having('count(*) = ' . count($cat_ids));
```

There yo go. The above will return all products that are simultaneously part of all provided categories. Thanks to activeDev and Jurgen for the help.

Comment: nice answer ! i'd love this query

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => '36,37')))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setPageSize(5);
```

This comes from http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-filter-product-collection-using-2-or-more-category-filters/, but seems slightly out of date.

Im not able to confirm if this works as im working on a version that currently contains no categories. but i am getting an empty collection back as expected, so let me know!

Comment: May heavily depend on the Magento version. For CE 1.4.1.1 using Sample Data 1.1.2 this fails with `Invalid attribute name:  entity_id` (at least for me).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does exactly the opposite of what I need, as the "in" basically gets all the products that have the category in A or B (at least for me using CE 1.7). So this will return all the products in the 2 categories. I need only the products that are found in BOTH A and B. If a product is found in one category but not in the other it shouldn't be found in the collection. I know I can use this solution and then filter the results further but is not ok as my collection is huge so I would need to filter this from the "query" level so to speak.